# How to make a button disabled until all fields are filled in?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hook-form

There are 3 inputs and a button to submit the form, I need to make the button inactive until all inputs have the correct values ​​that will satisfy the condition

```
export default function Registration() {
  const {...methods} = useForm<FormValues>();
  const navigation:NavigationProp<ParamListBase>= useNavigation()
  const [disable,setDisable] = useState(true);
  
  const onSubmit= (data:FormValues) => {
      navigation.navigate('congrats');
  };
  const onError: SubmitErrorHandler<FormValues> = (errors, e) => {
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.registration}>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.header}>Join Us</Text>
        <Text style={styles.description}>You will be able to fully communicate</Text>
        <FormProvider {...methods}>
          <TextInput
            label="Email"
            placeholder='Enter your e-mail'
            {...methods.register("email",{
              required:true,
              pattern:/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i
            })}
            errorStyle={methods.formState.errors.email?true:false}
          />
          {methods.formState.errors.email&&<Text style={styles.errrorMesage}>Enter correct e-mail!</Text>}
          <TextInput
            label="Password"
            placeholder='Enter your password'
            source={require('./eye.png')}
            errorStyle={methods.formState.errors.password?true:false}
            {...methods.register("password",{
              required:true,
              minLength:5
            })}
          />
           {methods.formState.errors.password&&<Text style={styles.errrorMesage}>Password field must be at leat 5 characters</Text>}
          <TextInput
            label="Confirm password"
            placeholder='Confirm your password'
            source={require('./eye.png')}
            errorStyle={methods.formState.errors.password?true:false}
            {...methods.register("confirmPassword",{
              required:true,
              validate:(value)=>{
                if(value!==methods.getValues('password')){
                  return "Both passwords must match"
                }
                return true
              }
            })}
          />
          { methods.formState.errors.confirmPassword&&<Text style={styles.errrorMesage}>{methods.formState.errors.confirmPassword.message}</Text>}
        </FormProvider>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.bottomPart}> 

        <View style={styles.bottomText}>
          <Text style={styles.bottomTextAlready}>
            Already have an account?{' '}
          </Text>
          <GreenLink Children={"Log In"}/>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.continueBtn}>
          <BigButton name={"Continue"} onPress={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit,onError)} disabled={disable}/>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
```

It is necessary that the bigbutton button is inactive until all 3 fields are error-free

My problem is that I don't understand how every time the form is measured there are errors, and if there are, then the button is disabled, and if not, then done actively.

Answer (score 1):

Create validation in onchange event on change event check all field value is null or not if not null so enabled it